# I don't understand how python methods within a class work

Tags: python, class

So I'm new to programming and I'm trying to learn how to code in uni.

We just started learning classes in python and I can't solve this problem.

I need to create a method reflect-x so that the variable y is negative.
Here is the code I wrote

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def reflect_x(self):
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = self.y
        else:
            self.y = -abs(self.y)
    def print(self):
        a = self.x , self.y
        print(tuple(a))
```

And this is what the site uses to check if the code is correct

```
p1 = Point(1, 4)
p1.reflect_x().print()

p2 = Point(-3, 5)
p2.reflect_x().print()

p3 = Point(-3, -5)
p3.reflect_x().print()
```

I keep getting " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print' " , and I don't know what to do.

Comment: `self.y = self.y` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: And `-abs(self.y)` is the same as `-self.y` after the `if` condition.

Comment: `a` is already a tuple, you don't need to call `tuple()`

Comment: By default, when a method (or function) doesn't explicitly `return` anything, it returns `None`. That's why you're seeing that error. And while you could just `return self`, this paradigm is not very often used in Python (unlike in Javascript). It's usually more common having one line that does the reflection (`p2.reflect_x()`) and theeen a `print(p2)`. You can overwrite how instances are represented on a terminal by overwriting the `__str__` method (see [this](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__str__/) tuturial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to programming!

Your method defining `reflect_x` returns `None`, which doesn't have a member function `print`. What you want is `reflect_x` to return a `Point` instead:

```
class Point:                                                                                            
    def __init__(self,x,y):                                                                             
        self.x=x                                                                                        
        self.y=y                                                                                        
                                                                                                        
    def reflect_x(self):                                                                                
        return Point(self.x, -self.y)                                                                   
                                                                                                        
    def printout(self):                                                                                 
        a = self.x , self.y                                                                             
        print(tuple(a))                                                                                 
                                                                                                        
p1 = Point(1, 4)                                                                                        
p1.printout()                                                                                           
                                                                                                        
p2 = Point(-3, 5)                                                                                       
p2.reflect_x().printout()                                                                               
                                                                                                        
p3 = Point(-3, -5)                                                                                      
p3.printout()
```

Note I changed `print`=>`printout`. Don't use reserved keywords for names in your developing!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call two methods (`reflect`, `print`) separately.

But if you have instinct to do the in such way you can approach it like this

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def reflect_x(self):
        if self.y > 0:
            self.y = -abs(self.y)
        return self # Return self will give you the instance itself

    def print(self):
        a = self.x , self.y
        print(tuple(a))

p1 = Point(1, 4)
p1.reflect_x().print()

p2 = Point(-3, 5)
p2.reflect_x().print()

p3 = Point(-3, -5)
p3.reflect_x().print()
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't call them like that because the site decided to use
p1.reflect_x().print()

Comment: If you need that, then `reflect_x` needs to `return self`